# Graphql-ws: separate websocket connection is opened for each subscription

Tags: reactjs, websocket, graphql, subscription, urql

I'm a newbie in websockets.
I use `urql` and `graphql-ws` (migrated from `subscriptions-transport-ws`) to get graphql subscriptions. The code is following:

```
export const useUrqlClient = () => {
  const headers = useHeaders();
  const client = useMemo(() => createUrqlClient(headers), [headers]);
  return client;
};

const createUrqlClient = (headers: any = defaultHeaders) => {
  return createClient({
    url: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    fetchOptions: {
      headers
    },
    exchanges: [
      ...defaultExchanges,
      subscriptionExchange({
        forwardSubscription: (operation) => {
          return {
            subscribe: (sink) => ({
              unsubscribe: wsClient(headers).subscribe(operation, sink)
            })
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  });
};

const wsClient = (headers: any) => createWSClient({
  url: WS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  connectionParams: () => ({
    headers
  })
});

const useHeaders = () => {
  const [authHeader, setAuthHeader] = useState<object>({});
  const { selectedToken } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedToken) {
      setAuthHeader(selectedToken ? { authorization: `Bearer ${selectedToken}` } : {});
    }
  }, [selectedToken]);

  return {
    ...defaultHeaders,
    ...authHeader
  };
};
```

Everything works fine BUT is it okay that separate websocket connection is opened for each subscription?
[image]

They are closed on leaving the page and another are created but is it expected?

Note: the same behaviour was on approach using subscriptions-transport-ws.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the client in [`lazy` mode](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions.md#lazy) which establishes WebSocket connections on-demand, this is the default.

Consider one of the 2 options:

1. Use the [client in `lazy = false` mode](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions.md#lazy) which will establish a connection with the server on create and keep it alive
2. Use the [client's `lazyCloseTimeout` option](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions.md#lazyclosetimeout) which will delay closing the connection in case of new subscriptions.